# position absolute, bottom 0, firefox not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, absolute

so im trying to place apostrow img at top left and bottom right of text, but firefox is not cooperating with me:

i have text in span, and placing imgs in before and after

```
.komentarz-main .content span{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

.komentarz-main .content span:after{
display: block;
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 11px;
height: 10px;
background-image: url("../img/cudzyslow.png");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
right: -15px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

firefox result:
[image]

chrome result:
[image]

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code, just replace your css code

```css
.komentarz-main .content span{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.komentarz-main .content span:after{
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 11px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url(../img/cudzyslow.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="komentarz-main">
<div class="content">
<span>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solved my problem, firefox and chrome cooperating now :) thanks
of course needed to set before similiar to this

Answer (score 0):

```
.komentarz-main .content span{ 
 display:inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: it's no longer sticking to text in <span>: overflowing on it or making large white spaces i don't know size of text in it

Comment: it doesn't metter. Add this style to `height:100%; position:relative;`